Valuation ("order of vanishing") on multivariable polynomial ring R[x1,...,xn] (in Roth's theorem on Diophantine Approximation)
Let $R$ be $\mathbb Z$ or a (char-$0$$\color{red}{?}$) field (I think in general, a characteristic $0$ integral domain should work$\color{red}{?}$ But perhaps someone can clarify this). In general for this post, all vectors $\vec \bullet$ will be length $n$. $\newcommand{\del}{\partial}$

For a polynomial $P \in R[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$ written as
$$P=\sum_{0\leq \vec j \leq \vec d} q(\vec j) x^{\vec j}$$  (so $\vec d$ is the length $n$ vector of maximal degrees of each variable, "$q$"
for "qoefficient"), and a multi-index $\mathbf i \in \mathbb{N}^n$, one has the formal derivative $\partial^{\mathbf i} P \in R[\vec x]$. Fixing a function $\phi:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$
(which we will later see must (?) be in fact be a dot product
$\phi(\vec x) = \vec x \cdot \vec w$ for some weight vector $\vec w \in \mathbb R_{>0}^n$), and a point $\vec x_0$, I define
$$\text{ind}_{(\vec x_0; \phi)}(P) :=\min_{0\leq \vec i \leq \vec d}\left\{\phi(\vec i) : [\partial^{\mathbf{i}} P](\vec x_0) \neq 0\right\},$$
which is a sort of measure for how "high" the order of vanishing of
$P$ at $\vec x_0$ is (indeed for $n=1$, this is the usual notion of
order of zero from say complex analysis). In particular of course, if
$P(\vec x_0)\neq 0$, then $\text{ind}_{(\vec x_0;\phi)} P = 0$ ("$P$
does not vanish at $\vec x_0$").

This notion appears as a part of the proof of Roth's theorem on Diophantine approximation, in e.g.

Bombieri & Gubler Heights in Diophantine Geometry Section 6.3 (pg. 156), or
Miller & Takloo-Bighash An Introduction to Modern Number Theory Lemma 6.3.2 (pg. 143), or
Section 3.4.3 (pg. 36) of Gaurish2016.


The claim is that this index (for any $\phi$ given by dot product as discussed above), at any point $\vec x_0$, is a valuation on the ring $R[\vec x]$.

The fact that

$\text{ind}_{(\vec x_0; \phi)}(P+Q) \geq \text{ind}_{(\vec x_0; \phi)} (P) \land \text{ind}_{(\vec x_0; \phi)}(Q)$,

and $\text{ind}_{(\vec x_0; \phi)}(PQ) \geq \text{ind}_{(\vec x_0; \phi)}(P)+\text{ind}_{(\vec x_0; \phi)}(Q)$,


are pretty straightforward (and only seem to use linearity of $\phi$$\color{red}{?}$ The proofs are really  more about the indices $\vec i$ themselves, rather than $\phi(\vec i)$.). See e.g. Lemma 3.4.6 (pg. 37-39) of Gaurish2016.

Where I am stuck: But $\text{ind}_{(\vec x_0; \phi)}(PQ) \leq \text{ind}_{(\vec x_0;\phi)}(P)+\text{ind}_{(\vec x_0; \phi)}(Q)$ is harder.

Gaurish2016 tried to show this by claiming that if $\vec j, \vec k$ were the argmin for the index of $P,Q$ resp. (so in particular, $\del^{\mathbf j}P(\vec x_0), \del^{\mathbf k}Q(\vec x_0)$ are non-zero), then $\vec i := \vec j + \vec k$ is s.t. $\del^{\mathbf i}(PQ)(\vec x_0)$ is non-zero.
This approach does not work, because take $P(x,y) = x-y, Q(x,y)=x+y-2$, $\vec x_0 = (1,1)$, and $\phi(x,y) = (x,y) \cdot (1,1) = x+y$. Then, one can check that the index of $P,Q$ is $1$, and $\vec j = (1,0), \vec k=(0,1)$ are argmin witnessing the minimum $1$, but for $\vec i = \vec j + \vec k = (1,1)$, we get that $\del^{(1,1)}(PQ)=\del_x\del_y(PQ)$ at $\vec x_0$ vanishes! It is still true that index of $PQ$ is $1+1$ though, but one can only see that at $\del^{(2,0)}$ or $\del^{(0,2)}$, not $\del^{(1,1)}$.

EDIT 11/29/24: perhaps https://diposit.ub.edu/dspace/bitstream/2445/199221/2/tfg_valcarce_dalmau_eduard.pdf Lemma 4.5, pg. 19 fixes the proof, using lexicographic ordering (though there's the tiniest missing detail of the coefficient/constant $C_{\ldots}$ being non-zero).
I'll leave the post up since I think the list of resources is good. Perhaps the result is already written up as clean/well-notated/elegantly as possible, though of course I'd be happy to see someone else try to explain it, once and for all (with as general a ring $R$ as reasonably possible), as an answer!

Note: Just because there's a valuation on some ring, it's not necessarily a valuation ring!

@LukasHeger oh... is it true in this case though?

No. The polynomial ring over another ring is never a valuation ring.
